# LINQ to XML (Dynamic XML)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file which has kind of a similar structure that you can see below:
I would like to select title and subitems using [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML_.28formerly_called_XLINQ.29). The difficulties that I have: sometimes a subitem can be just one and sometimes it can be 20 subitems, and I need to add them to List<string>.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <title>Name of the title</title>
        <subitem>Test</subitem>
        <subitem1>Test</subitem1>
        <subitem2>Test</subitem2>
        <subitem3>Test</subitem3>
        <subitem4>Test</subitem4>
        <subitem5>Test</subitem5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Name of the title</title>
        <subitem>Test</subitem>
        <subitem1>Test</subitem1>
        <subitem2>Test</subitem2>
        <subitem3>Test</subitem3>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Name of the title</title>
        <subitem>Test</subitem>
        <subitem1>Test</subitem1>
    </item>
</items>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you would like for an output?

Answer (score 1):

The solution, including getting the titles, is:

```
XDocument yourXDocument = XDocument.Load(yourXmlFilePath);
IEnumerable<Tuple<XElement, IEnumerable<XElement>>> yourSubItems =
    yourXDocument.Root.Descendants()
                 .Where(xelem => xelem.Name == "title")
                 .Select(xelem => new Tuple<XElement, IEnumerable<XElement>>(xelem, xelem.Parent.Elements().Where(subelem => subelem.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("subitem")));
```

Comment: @Eugene: A tuple gives you a generic construct to group different types of data together, a Tuple<string,int,DateTime> would be an object which has property Item1 of type string, Item2 of type int, and Item3 of type DateTime, the tuple I created has Item1 which is the title XElement, and Item2 which is an IEnumerable of XElements representing the title's subitems.

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var query = from i in xdoc.Descendants("item")
            select new
            {
                Title = (string)i.Element("title"),
                Subitems = i.Elements()
                            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("subitem"))
                            .Select(e => (string)e)
                            .ToList()
            };
```